# How Can I Query the Parent Record Using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, office365api

To check if paymenttype equal credit account **[entity form: auto_paymenttype]**

Then , if payment amount <= resit amount, it will save else > prevent save (popup message invalid: payment amount should lower than resit amount)**[entity form: auto_resittype]**

Hi guys, It could be great if someone could re-code and help me on this.I am new in D365 and JS. Basically, I have entities which is auto_paymenttype and auto_resittype and their parent is Payment. How can I query the parent adjustment record using JS. I have provide my current code, please help me to review it.  I have try everything but so far no luck. Sorry for my unprofessional picture. But I hope you understand it and could help me to code for this situation. Thank you.

```js
function resitApproveAmount(executionContext) {
        try {
        const object = {};
        object.fctx = executionContext.getFormContext();
            object.saveEvent = object.fctx.getEventArgs();
            object.paymentamount = object.fctx.getAttribute("auto_paymentamount").getValue();
            object.resitamount = object.fctx.getAttribute("auto_resitamount").getValue();
            
            
        object.paymenttype = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("auto_paymenttype").getValue();
            if (object.paymenttype != null) {
                object.autoGUID = object.paymenttype[0].id.substring(1, 37);
            }
             
            Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("auto_paymenttype", "$select=auto_name").then(
            function success(result) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                  object.auto_name = result.entities[i]["auto_name"];}
                  if(object.auto_name == "Credit Account"){
                  if (object.paymenttamount >= object.resitamount) {
                    alert("Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount.");
                    object.saveEvent.preventDefault();
                    } 
                else 
                    {object.fctx.data.save();}
                       }
                },
                    
         
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            );
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

[click here for picture overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIDEh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You code implies `auto_paymentamount` and `auto_resitamount` exist on entity `Payment` but you ERD shows them existing on entity `Resit Type`.

If they are on the `Payment` entity then your can retrieve their values  as in your question:

```js
const paymentAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymentamount").getValue();
const resitAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_resitamount").getValue();
```

Otherwise you need to retrieve the `Resit Type` record related to your `Payment` record, using the WebApi. If this is the case I assume you have a lookup from `Payment` to `Resit Type`.

**Assuming** `auto_paymentamount` and `auto_resitamount` exist on entity `Payment` your code can be simplified to the following two solutions. Both solutions assume this function is called during the `onsave` event.

### Solution 1 - Retrieve the related Payment Type Record

```js
function resitApproveAmount(executionContext) {
    try {
        // Get the form context
        const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

        // Extract attribute values from the form
        const paymentAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymentamount").getValue();
        const resitAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_resitamount").getValue();
        const paymentTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymenttype").getValue();

        // Exit as payment type is not set
        if (!paymentTypeLookup) return;

        // Extract the payment type record ID from the payment type lookup
        const paymentTypeId = paymentTypeLookup[0].id.substring(1, 37);
         
        // Retrieve a SINGLE auto_paymenttype based on lookup ID on form
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("auto_paymenttype", paymentTypeId, "$select=auto_name").then(
            function (paymentType) 
            {
                // If the payment type is credit account then check payment amount and resit amount
                if (paymentType.auto_name.toLowerCase() == "Credit Account".toLowerCase()) 
                {
                    if (paymentAmount >= resitAmount) {
                        formContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
                        Xrm.Navigation.openErrorDialog({message:"Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount."})
                    }
                }
                //Otherwise do nothing
            },
            function (error) 
            {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        );
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

### Solution 2 - Hard Code the Payment Type Record ID

This can be used if you can guarantee your payment type record ID's will be the same across all environments (i.e. Payment type records are migrated using a data migration tool)

```js
function resitApproveAmount(executionContext) {
    try {
        // Get the form context
        const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

        // Extract attribute values from the form
        const paymentAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymentamount").getValue();
        const resitAmount = formContext.getAttribute("auto_resitamount").getValue();
        const paymentTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymenttype").getValue();

        // Exit as payment type is not set
        if (!paymentTypeLookup) return;

        // Extract the payment type record ID from the payment type lookup
        const paymentTypeId = paymentTypeLookup[0].id.substring(1, 37);

        // Exit if payment type id is not "Credit Account"
        if (paymentTypeId.toLowerCase() !== "Hard Code Credit Account GUID here / retrieve environment variable") return;

        if (paymentAmount >= resitAmount) {
            formContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
            Xrm.Navigation.openErrorDialog({message:"Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount."})
        }
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

### Notes

To help with questions like this in future I would recommend drawing an Entity Relationship Diagram. This helps us understand your entity model and relationships, which helps us answer questions accurately the first time.

[Diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net/) is a great way to draw an ERD for free

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had another read of the question and think I better understand your entity model:

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

Like my previous answer this solution assumes this function is called during the onsave event on `Payment`. I use async/await and [async onsave events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2021wave1/power-apps/async-onsave-events) to simplify the retrieval of `Payment Type` and `Resit Type`. Like my other answer, if you **know** Payment Type GUIDs will be the same across environments you can hard code the Payment Type ID, and check the ID against the lookup ID on payment, to save yourself a WebApi call.

```js
/**
 * On Save of Payment record
 * @param executionContext 
 * @returns 
 */

async function onSave(executionContext) {
    try {
        // Get the form context
        const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        const paymentTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("auto_paymenttype").getValue();
        const resitTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("aut_resittype").getValue();

        // Exit as payment type is not set
        if (!paymentTypeLookup || !resitTypeLookup) return;

        // Extract related entity IDs
        const paymentTypeId = paymentTypeLookup[0].id.substring(1, 37);
        const resitTypeId = resitTypeLookup[0].id.substring(1, 37);

        // Get related records
        const [paymentTypeResult, resitTypeResult] = await Promise.all([
            Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("auto_paymenttype", paymentTypeId),
            Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("auto_resittype", resitTypeId)
        ]);

        // Evaluate payment type and resit type and prevent save if required
        if (paymentTypeResult.auto_name.toLowerCase() === "Credit Account".toLowerCase() 
        && resitTypeResult.auto_paymentAmount >= resitTypeResult.auto_resitAmount) 
        {
            formContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
            Xrm.Navigation.openErrorDialog({message:"Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount."})
        }
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!I have try the solution 1, but i have an issue running it doesnt run starting from, when i turned on the debugger, `const resitTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("aut_resittype").getValue();` until the retrieverecord Api. so it means it cant get value from paymentTypeLookup and im not sure why.